# transfer mysqld output to a text file

Tags: debian, mysql

I tried the following in debian:

`mysqld restart > mysqld.txt`

But I can see nothing in `mysqld.txt`, while I can still see the output of `mysqld restart` on screen. I wonder why.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer to this question, or the other questions you have posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` redirects [stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). You need to use `2>` to redirect stderr, or `&>` for both.